# C++ brace initilization with template parameter

Tags: c++, templates

I'm almost certain this has been answered somewhere, but I can't find it, so I'll just ask.

Compiles fine

```
template <int SIZE, unsigned int NUMSYNC>
class MyClass{
private:
    std::uniform_int_distribution<int> randomNumberDistribution{ 0, SIZE };
}
```

Does not compile (constant SIZE is not a type name)

```
template <int SIZE, unsigned int NUMSYNC>
class MyClass{
private:
    std::uniform_int_distribution<int> randomNumberDistribution( 0, SIZE );
}
```

I'm trying to understand the difference and why the brace-initialization works, as opposed to the traditional one.

I'm compiling with C++14

Comment: When asking questions about code that leads to build errors, then please include the *full* and *complete* error output (copy-pasted as text) in the question.

Comment: This isn't related to templates. `(...)` simply doesn't work for default member initializers, probably because it would be hard to distinguish from method declarations.

Comment: To avoid to repeat the error with most vexing parse.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is due to the definition in the standard. Otherwise, it could be impossible for the compiler to distinguish it from a member function declaration when parsing the code.

> 2) Through a default member initializer, which is a **brace or equals initializer** included in the member declaration and is used if the member is omitted from the member initializer list of a constructor.
>   (Emphasis by me)

https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/data_members